# Show/hide password icon in ionic deletes already written password

Tags: button, ionic-framework, passwords

My issue: I write half of the password, click the button to show me the passwod and when I get back to the field and continue writing,  it deletes the digits I have already written. (I am using it in a ion-list.)

HTML:

> Blockquote

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-input [type]="passwordType" [(ngModel)]="password" 
         id="password"></ion-input>                                    
         <ion-icon name="eye" [color]="passwordShown === true ? 'black' : 
      'white'" item-end (click)="passwordToggle()"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
```

TS:

```
 passwordToggle(){
   if(this.passwordShown){
    this.passwordShown=false;
    this.passwordType = 'password';
   }else{
    this.passwordShown=true;
    this.passwordType = "";
}
```

}

> Blockquote

Comment: On the else condition, try making the type into 'text' instead of empty string

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. In the ion-input I added clearOnEdit="false", this prevents the deletion of the password. Thanks to the youtube channel Technbuzz!